# Best practices for serializing complex models in Flink

Tags: machine-learning, apache-flink

I am using a UDF to apply some ML models to a data stream. Because the `Model` class (from a third party library) cannot be serialized by Flink automatically, I am using two variables as illustrated below:

```scala
class MyUDF extends KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, ModelDef, Data, Prediction]
  with CheckpointedFunction {

  // To hold loaded models
  @transient private var models: HashMap[(String, String), Model] = _

  // For serialization purposes
  @transient private var modelsBytes: MapState[(String, String), Array[Bytes]] = _

  ...
}
```

Where:

- `models` holds the loaded (running) models (created from a `ModelDef`, basically a string)
- `modelsBytes` is the real (keyed) state, which holds the same models but as a blob of bytes so that checkpoints work well.

The overall solution is simple (just requires to invoke `fromBytes`/`toBytes` on my models when restoring/saving them) but I don't know if this is a common/best practice. Having two variables for essentially the same thing looks like a quirk. For instance, [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/fdp-modelserver/blob/master/flinkserver/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/modelserver/typeschema/ModelTypeSerializer.scala) you can find an example which uses a `TypeSerializer[Option[Model]]` instead, which looks cleaner but also more complicated to implement.

So, basically:

- Should I use the `TypeSerializer` approach or having a somehow duplicated state for running/serialized models is ok?
- Also, if you could please point me to some docs/examples regarding custom types serialization in Flink, that would be great, generally I find the official docs a bit lacking on this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with a heap state backend and a custom `TypeSerializer`.

Heap state backend will only serialize the data on checkpoint and else keeps the data as is. So you have almost no performance penalty when using that backend over managing the map itself. However, it will remove the need to perform the serialization and sync manually.

Answer (score 1):

Judicious denormalization of data for the sake of performance is a very common pattern.  If you're not using too much memory then stick with this approach.